# How can i pass values to a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement the autocomplete method for textboxes.

I would like to use the example based on jquerys autocomplete provided [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#overview)

```
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

The first and Main problem is that i do not know the way of passing my values to the `source:`

By saying that i mean, supposing i have a a server-side ASP.NET function
GetTheResults as listof(string) or
GetTheResults as string ()

how am i supposed to pass those values as source required by the auto-complete?

The second problem is that the specific way does not use AJAX.
Which means i guess on the load of the form i will load all the available values to the source. Isn't that an overkill?

What do you suggest instead?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Consider http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/ which allows AJAX loaded values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, maybe I misunderstood - is `GetTheResults` a server-side ASP.NET function? You didn't say. This assumes it's a client-side JavaScript function. If it is server-side, why not implement the AJAX way?

---

If `GetTheResults` returns all values then I think you can just fill it in inline, i.e.

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: GetTheResults()
    }
});
```

The control will then filter the list for display. Or you can use the function source mechanism as documented on that page, e.g.

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = GetTheResultsForInput(request.term);
        response(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeap! GetTheResults is a server-side ASP Function. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead manually write out the content from the server to the client.  Try creating a public method called:

```
public string GetJs()
{
   var data = this.GetTheResults();
   string output = "[";
   bool comma = false;

   foreach (var i in data)
   {
      if (comma)
        output += ", ";
      else
        comma = true;

       output += '" + i + "'";
   }

   return output + "]";
}
```

And change your client-side script to look like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: <%= GetJs() %>
});
  });
```

You may have to inject the <%= %> as a string, and instead do:

```
source: eval("<%= GetJs() %>")
```

Or you could write that entire JS from the page to the output.

HTH.